# no se puede acomodar array VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Por que no me acomoda mis registros numeroCliente - nombreCliente, este es mi array en VB.NET

```html
    Dim a As String
    a = Request.Form("numeroCliente")
    
    Dim b As String
    b = Request.Form("nombreCliente")

    
    Dim numeroCliente(,) As String = {{a} , {b}}

    
    For Each valor As String In numeroCliente

        For Each valor1 As String In numeroCliente

        Response.Write("El valor es numeroCliente " & valor & "nombreCliente" & valor1 )
        Next
    Next
```

lo coloca de esta forma 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que intento hacer es recuperar datos que hay en las filas de una tabla en un array para poder insertarlos en una tabla de BD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas recorriendo mal, con For Each vas a recorrer de forma secuencial, no hay forma de decir que dimensión recorrer.

Deberías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To numeroCliente.GetLength(0) - 1
      For y As Integer = 0 To numeroCliente.GetLength(1) - 1
          str = str + " " + numeroCliente(x, y)
      Next
 Next
```

Con GetLength(num) obtienes la longitud de la dimensión especificada.